# Forbidding the ability to move, add items in a GUI on Minecraft in Java

Tags: java, java-8, minecraft

**Information :**
Spigot : 1.12 &     Java version: 8

I try to make that when a player the GUI, that he can take items once the GUI closed since: https://gyazo.com/27ccc89e0b5c8f0780bcdca906eab5af
So I created a new class to interact with an event (InventoryClickEvent) the problem is that when it applies it applies from the beginning to the end, except that I would like to put it in a condition: If the player opens the GUI he can't take items in this GUI, and if he closes it the event will be invalid and the player will be able to take items in the gamemode/or move items from his inventory (for example)

And the problem I have is that I don't know how to apply it in a loop I created (for my GUI)
I use the CommandExecutor / which does not allow me to use an event (I think)

**My code :**
Commands : https://bin.readthedocs.fr/jeedur.txt
ClickEvent : https://bin.readthedocs.fr/nermit.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a static list (as a field) that stores all players who have the GUI open. When a player executes the command, you add them to the list. When he closes the inventory (InventoryCloseEvent) you remove the player. In the InventoryClickEvent you then check whether the player is in the list. If so, you block the event.

Code parts:

Put this in top of your Commands class (import List and ArrayList from java.util.*) [Commands line 20]:

```
public static List<Player> playersInInventory = new ArrayList<>();
```

Right before you open the inventory [Commands line 142]:

```
Commands.playersInInventory.add(player);
```

In your InventoryCloseEvent [Create this event]:

```
Commands.playersInInventory.remove(event.getPlayer());
```

Then you can use this in your InventoryClickEvent [the only content of your event]:

```
if (Commands.playersInInventory.contains((Player) (event.getWhoClicked()))) {
    event.setCancelled(true);
}
```

This code should work fine, but I haven't tested it. If it doesn't work, please let me know.

Comment: Hello, 
I had already thought about this way of doing it, the problem is that in my code I can't implement it at all, I have errors everywhere when I do it, would it be possible for you to explain me a little more please? In any case, thank you for your comment, I must admit that for the past week I've been lost.

Comment: Sure. I'll add the lines you have to put this code. But I can't see your ClickEvent file. Can you reupload your this file? (Don't forget to import List and ArrayList)

Comment: Yes of course then I did as you said but it's the "getPlayer" method that gives me an error at the moment: https://prnt.sc/11h8ucm // my code (class ClickEvent: https://bin.readthedocs.fr/lionus.txt)

Full code : 
1) Main: https://bin.readthedocs.fr/bleyen.txt
2) Commands : https://bin.readthedocs.fr/ivener.txt
3) ClickEvent : https://bin.readthedocs.fr/grenac.txt

Comment: Shouldn't I replace getPlayer() with: getWhoClicked()?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. It has been a while... Use e.getWhoClicked(). This gives you an HumanEntity. You have to cast it to Player.

Comment: Okay no worries your help is very much appreciated, I spent the worst week of my life on this project, just for a stupid error, and by putting the getWhoClicked() here is the result :  https://streamable.com/cbey5t

Comment: Your `closeEvent(...)` needs a `@EventHandler` annotation. Otherwise the event doesn't get called if you close your inventory and you never remove a Player from the list. So clicking stays disabled.